# How to extract only certain fields from Http response object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm fairly new to Angular and I'm trying to get only certain values from the Http response object.

In my service, I'm doing a get request to fetch weather data for a given city like so:

```
export class CityService {
  private baseUrl = 'https://api.openweathermap.org';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCity(name: string){
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/data/2.5/weather?q=${name}&appid=${environment.weatherApiKey}`);
  }
}
```

Now, in the component, I'm logging out the response like so:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cityService.getCity('lucija').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }
```

The response itself it's just one object with many fields (also nested ones), which most of them I do not need.

I've also set up an interface where I would like to "save" in those certain response fields:

```
export interface City {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  icon: string;
  main: object;
  search: string;
}
```

How can I do that? Cheers!

EDIT:
Based on the answer below I got 2 errors, which I resolved like so:

```
getCity(name: string): Observable<City>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/data/2.5/weather?q=${name}&appid=${environment.weatherApiKey}`)
    .pipe(map((res: any) => <City>{
      name: res.name,
      description: res.weather[0].description,
      icon: `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/${res.weather[0].icon}.png`,
      main: res.main,
      search: name
    }));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution could be to map the object in your service. Then your service will return the City Object.

```js
export class CityService {
  private baseUrl = 'https://api.openweathermap.org';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getCity(name: string): Observable<City>{
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/data/2.5/weather?q=${name}&appid=${environment.weatherApiKey}`)
     .pipe(map((res) => { return { name: res.cityName }; }); // only added name as example. In the final code map all the values to the correct City field.
  }
}
```

If you do not want your service to always return the City object you can do this mapping in your component.

Comment: I'm getting 2 errors now:
1. Type 'Observable<void>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<City>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'City'.
2. Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: Made an edit. Coding in the stackoverflow text editor.my bad. Had some syntax error. You should return in the map.

Comment: No worries. I also found how to fix it and I've edited my post. Cheers again!